# How to work with gemspec add_runtime_dependency and `bundle install`

Tags: ruby, bundle, bundler, gemspecs

I have a codebase which has a gemspec file like:

```rb
require "rubygems"
::Gem::Specification.new do |specification|
  specification.add_development_dependency "yard", "~> 0.9"
  specification.add_runtime_dependency "dry-validation", "~> 0.13"
end
```

`bundle install` will install both dependency types. So I want to just install the runtime dependencies for my CI scripts. I see `bundle install --with <group>` exists, but I don't have groups. Run interactively, the returned specification has an empty result returned from `.groups`. I would love to rationalize these two worlds. Must I explicitly add a group for each gem dependency? Does add_runtime_dependency and add_development_dependency even make a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [bundler's documentation](https://bundler.io/guides/creating_gem.html#testing-our-gem)

> Because we have the `gemspec` method call in our *Gemfile*, Bundler will automatically add this gem to a group called “development” which then we can reference any time we want to load these gems with the following line:
>
> ```rb
> Bundler.require(:default, :development)
> ```

in your case, if you wish to install all rubygems that are not for development, then try

```sh
bundle install --without development
```

for future bundler version, you can configure it locally (or globally)

```sh
bundle config set --local without 'development'
```

to make it all work, verify that you have a `Gemfile` in your project, which will look like

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

source 'https://rubygems.org'

gemspec
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mr. There is no Gemfile, just a Gemspec. There is a gems.rb which does define the groups development, test, runtime and includes just one gem each. However, the Gemspec seems to be controlling what `bundle install` is doing, not the gems.rb.

Comment: Thanks. I have now been able to verify that the group *development* is associated with any specification.add_development_dependency statements. It turned out the secondary dependencies were looking like they were overlapping. In addition, the group *runtime* is associated with specification.add_runtime_dependency.